# C QueueLinkedList string variable not working

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
#include<stdlib.h>

struct customer
{
  int phoneNum;
  char *name;
  struct customer *nxt;
};

struct customer *initialNode(int i, char *n);
int isEmpty(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail);
void enqueue(int phNum1, char *cName1, struct customer *tail);
void dequeue(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail);
void display(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail);

int main()
{
  int phNum;
  char *cName;
  int choice;

  struct customer *head;
  struct customer *tail;
  head = initialNode(0, NULL);
  tail = initialNode(0, NULL);
  head->nxt = tail;
  tail->nxt = head;

  while (choice !=4)
  {
    printf("\nEnter your option:");
    printf("\n1. Enqueue new customer. \n2. Dequeue customer. \n3. Display customer in queue. \n4. Exit. \nOption: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1: 
      {
        printf("\nEnter customer phone number: ");
        scanf("%d", &phNum);
        printf("\nEnter customer name: ");
        scanf("%s", cName);
        enqueue(phNum, cName, tail);
        break;
      }
      case 2:
      { 
        dequeue(head, tail);
        break;
      }
      case 3: 
      {
        display(head, tail);
        break;
      }
      default: 
      {
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
          printf("\nInvalid option!\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}

struct customer *initialNode(int i, char *n)
{
  struct customer *newCustomer = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  newCustomer->phoneNum = i;
  newCustomer->name = n;
  newCustomer->nxt = NULL;
  return newCustomer; 
}

int isEmpty ( struct customer *head, struct customer *tail)
{
  if (head->nxt == tail)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;   //cannot is full because it is not array, have no size limitation
}

void enqueue(int phNum1, char *cName1, struct customer *tail)
{
  struct customer *nC = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  nC = initialNode(phNum1, cName1);
  nC->nxt = tail;

  tail->nxt->nxt = nC;
  tail->nxt = nC;

  printf("\nSuccessfully enqueue a customer!\n");
}

void dequeue(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail)
{
  struct customer *removedCustomer = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  if (isEmpty(head, tail) == 1)
  {
    printf("\nThe queue is empty!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    removedCustomer = head->nxt;
    printf("\nFirst customer is removed.\n");

    head->nxt = head->nxt->nxt;
  }
}

void display(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail)
{
  struct customer *tempH = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  tempH = head;
  tempH = tempH->nxt;
  if (isEmpty(head, tail) == 1)
  {
    printf("\nThe queue is empty!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\n===Current customer list===");
    while (tempH != tail)
    {
      printf("\n\tCustomer phone number : %d", tempH->phoneNum);
      printf("\n\tCustomer name: %s\n", tempH->name);
      tempH = tempH->nxt;
    }
  }
}
```

The code is suppose to make queue of a list of customer that user input their phone number and name, code is working well but when i input a new customer, the customer before's name all somehow become the latest customer's name..
How do i solve this? Do i declare a 2D string array to collect different set of customer's name?

Comment: When you enqueue or dequeue, the tail pointer needs to be updated. You are not doing that. Also, you are initializing the list initially with two blank nodes.

Comment: Also, in the `initialname` function you are directly assigning the string to `newCustomer->name', You need to allocate the memory for this per structure element.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje 
the tail->nxt->nxt = nC;
  tail->nxt = nC;
in enqueue needs to be in the main, after enqueue called to be updated? im not sure if the pointer struct is coming out from the enqueue function like using pointers.. 

Is this correct for initialName?
newCustomer->name = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
newCustomer->name = n;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the below issues with the code.

1. The `head` and `tail` should be initialized to `NULL`. This signifies an empty list.
2. In the `initialnode` function you are directly assigning the scanned pointer as `newCustomer->name = n`. This is wrong. As you have declared the struct as having a character pointer, you need to also allocate space for each string separately.
3. The enqueue and dequeue functions can change the value of the `head` and `tail` pointers in the main function. You can change the function declarations to pass a double pointer for this.
4. You also need to free the struct on dequeue. This is strictly not necessary in a small program but is a good practice anyway to avoid memory leaks in larger programs.
5. In the display function you are having an unnessary `malloc` which needs to be removed. This function does not need to allocate memory.
6. The variable `choice` in main is not initailized.

Please see the code below

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct customer
{
  int phoneNum;
  char *name;
  struct customer *nxt;
};

struct customer *initialNode(int i, char *n);
int isEmpty(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail);
void enqueue(int phNum1, char *cName1, struct customer **head, struct customer **tail);
void dequeue(struct customer **head, struct customer **tail);
void display(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail);

int main(void)
{
  int phNum;
  char cName[51]; // max name length supported
  int choice = 0;

  struct customer *head;
  struct customer *tail;
  head = NULL;
  tail = NULL;

  while (choice !=4)
  {
    printf("\nEnter your option:");
    printf("\n1. Enqueue new customer. \n2. Dequeue customer. \n3. Display customer in queue. \n4. Exit. \nOption: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1: 
      {
        printf("\nEnter customer phone number: ");
        scanf("%d", &phNum);
        printf("\nEnter customer name: ");
        scanf("%s", cName);
        enqueue(phNum, cName, &head, &tail);
        break;
      }
      case 2:
      { 
        dequeue(&head, &tail);
        break;
      }
      case 3: 
      {
        display(head, tail);
        break;
      }
      default: 
      {
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
          printf("\nInvalid option!\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

struct customer *initialNode(int i, char *n)
{
  int len;
  struct customer *newCustomer = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  newCustomer->phoneNum = i;
  len = strlen(n);
  newCustomer->name = malloc(len +1);
  strcpy(newCustomer->name, n);
  newCustomer->nxt = NULL;
  return newCustomer; 
}

int isEmpty ( struct customer *head, struct customer *tail)
{
  if ((head == NULL) && (tail == NULL))
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;   //cannot is full because it is not array, have no size limitation
}

void enqueue(int phNum1, char *cName1, struct customer **head, struct customer **tail)
{
  struct customer *nC = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  nC = initialNode(phNum1, cName1);
  if (isEmpty(*head,*tail))
  {
    *head = nC;
    *tail = nC;
  }
  else if (*head == *tail)  // single element
  {
    (*head)->nxt = nC;
    *tail = nC;
  }
  else
  {
    (*tail)->nxt = nC;
    *tail = nC;
  }
  printf("\nSuccessfully enqueue a customer!\n");
}

void dequeue(struct customer **head, struct customer **tail)
{
  struct customer *removedCustomer = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
  if (isEmpty(*head, *tail) == 1)
  {
    printf("\nThe queue is empty!\n");
  }
  else if (*head == *tail) // single element
  {
    removedCustomer = *head;
    free(removedCustomer->name);
    free(removedCustomer);
    *head = NULL;
    *tail = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    removedCustomer = *head;
    *head = (*head)->nxt;
    free(removedCustomer->name);
    free(removedCustomer);
    printf("\nFirst customer is removed.\n");
  }
}

void display(struct customer *head, struct customer *tail)
{
  struct customer *tempH;
  tempH = head;
  if (isEmpty(head, tail) == 1)
  {
    printf("\nThe queue is empty!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\n===Current customer list===");
    while (tempH != NULL)
    {
      printf("\n\tCustomer phone number : %d", tempH->phoneNum);
      printf("\n\tCustomer name: %s\n", tempH->name);
      tempH = tempH->nxt;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it a must to allocate the size of the any char pointer like what you did with newCustomer?

Comment: in the enqueue function, the default value for `if (isEmpty(*head,*tail))` is 0? Do we need to do it like `if (isEmpty(*head,*tail) == 0)`?

Comment: "is it a must to allocate the size of the any char pointer" -> Yes with the current struct definition. If however you define the struct as  `struct customer
    {
      int phoneNum;
      char name[51];
      struct customer *nxt;
    };` then you do not need to `malloc` while creating the new node. There are pros and cons for each approach

Comment: "in the enqueue function, the default value ,,," -> The empty function returns `1` when empty. What I have done is equivalent to `if (isEmpty(*head,*tail) == 1)`